# Spring - Service layer methods generic vs specific

Tags: java, spring, service, layer

I'm currently working on an application where I can see the following:

- Controller A : service.getSession(userId, Status.Started);
- Controller B: service.getSession(userId, Status.Done);

(where Status represent an enum of possible statuses)

- Service: getSession(Long id, Status status);

I find it not right, as users who are going to access controller A have certain roles and users accessing B others and there should be 2 services methods:

- getSessionReady(Long id);
- getSessionClosed(Long id);

Doing so I can clearly use Spring security and make sure that the right role access the right service methods. It makes me create two methods but it makes easier to secure the app and the goal of the service layer is to actually restrict access to limit logic errors right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The more generic you make the service layer (or any class, in fact), the less value it adds.

You want your service layer to restrict access and make sure only valid calls make it into the domain.

Also, more methods is not a bad thing!  As long as they make sense, feel free.  Usually a method with an extra parameter that triggers different behaviour is a code smell, and should be split up.